# Custom Node Logger

Tags: node.js

**process.env.LOG_LEVEL** inside my node js project always having **undefined** value while running my logger inside lambda.

What might be the problem for this?

Comment: Why do you expect `process.env.LOG_LEVEL` to be set? (note: I don't know anything about lambda)

Comment: I expect this env variable to send me the LOG_LEVEL

Comment: Lambda here means AWS lambda .

Comment: Yes but how are you defining the env fir the lambda?  Are you setting them via https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.